# Pasar valor de un input a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

El valor lo envío desde una página a un modal de Bootstrap de la siguiente manera por medio del `data-book-id=""` de la etiqueta `<a></a>`.

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){                                                                                                
        echo "    <tr>";
        echo " "?><td style="display:none;"><?php  
        echo $row['SecCarro']."</td>";           
        echo "    <td>".$row['CorreoCliente']."</td>";                                                  
        echo "    <td><a rel=\"tooltip\"title=\"Ver\" href=\"sys/detalleped.php\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#proModal\" data-book-id=\"".$row['SecCarro']."\" > <i class=\"fa fa-eye fa-lg\" ></i></a></td>";                                         
        echo "    </tr>"; }?>
```

Lo capturo de la siguiente manera.

```
<script>
$('#proModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);    
});</script>

<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>  
<?php
     $var =?? // Aqui necesito el valor del input... :/
?>
```

Y aquí es donde me he quedado, agradecería cualquier ayuda posible.

Comment: Varias cosas, puedes por favor redactar mejor tu pregunta, no se entiende lo que quieres hacer. Recuerda que SO esta basado en preguntas y respuestas cerradas no abiertas, asi que intenta algo equivocate y nos dices que salió. Por último si creo que entendí lo que pusiste, pues no puedes usar php dinámicamente en el lado del cliente. Como este es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, en el servidor mismo se compila y se lo envia a la vista, por lo tanto no se pueden hace rmodificaciones del codigo php en el cliente. Pero tal vez con una mejor explicación podamos todos entender, gracias,

Answer (score 3):

Recuerda primero que todo, que `PHP` es un lenguaje enfocado por el lado del servidor y JavaScript o JQuery es un lenguaje por el lado del cliente. Por tanto lo que uno puede hacer es un "engaño" a lo que uno entiende, haciendo envío al servidor desde JQuery.

Por lo que puedes implementar `AJAX` para el envío desde el input a un archivo `php` en tiempo real, haciendo parecer que se esta ejecutando por el lado del cliente.

Puedes implementar Ajax con Jquery del siguiente modo:

**CLIENTE:**

```
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>  
<script>
  var dato = $('#bookId').val();
    $.ajax({
      data: {"dato" : dato},
      url: "archivoEnviarDato.php",
      type: "post",
      success:  function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
 </script>
```

**SERVIDOR:**

```
<?php
    $var = $_POST['dato'];
    //Procedimiento a realizar
?>
```

Espero que entiendas que tu situación esta por el lado del cliente por lo que veo y por tanto como php vive en el servidor, debes hacer un envío de mensaje con el dato del input que necesitas.

*Esto ayudara a que no tengas que salir de tu pagina actual. Vale decir, puedes seguir interactuando con la pantalla que estas.*

**Nota:**

Si requieres que el archivo `php` de un valor de vuelta y JQuery lo tome, la forma mas sencilla es la siguiente:

**SERVIDOR:**

```
<?php
    $var = $_POST['dato'];
    echo $var.' de vuelta'; // concatenamos y devolvemos el valor a la pagina que requirió de esta solicitud
?>
```

**CLIENTE:**

```
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>  
<script>
  var dato = $('#bookId').val();
    $.ajax({
       data: {"dato" : dato},
       url: "archivoEnviarDato.php",
       type: "post",
    success:  function (response) {
       alert(response); //Arrojara un alert colocando el input + ' de vuelta'
    });
 </script>
```

> Si estas ocupando base de datos, cuidado tanto con la **Inyeccion SQL** y el **Ataque XSS**

Espero que te pueda ser de ayuda. Saludos y éxito!

Answer (score 2):

El código PHP solamente se ejecutará si existe una solicitud del cliente, por lo tanto puedes hacerlo usando un **`<form>`** o bien a través de **`AJAX`**, pero en este caso te recomiendo usar un **`<form>`**.

Quedando el código **`HTML`**:

```
<form action="tu_pagina.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
     <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Y el **simple guión en `PHP`**:

```
<?php
$bookid = $_POST["bookId"]; //Ya tienes el valor del input en una variable PHP, ahora ya haz lo que desees con ella
?>
```

> **ADVERTENCIA:** si esa variable la vas a transladar a una base de datos
>   mucho cuidadito con la **inyección SQL**, el código que te he mostrado **NO
>   la evita**.
>   **[Aquí tienes buena información sobre el tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)**.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda